# SonarQube 5.2 Upgrade failed

Tags: sql, sonarqube, upgrade

I tried upgrading SonarQube from 5.1.2 to 5.2, but the Upgrade failed. I have the following message in the Sonar.log:

```
2015.11.23 07:44:36 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Cannot find the object "project_links" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: ALTER TABLE project_links ADD [component_uuid] NVARCHAR(50)
2015.11.23 08:03:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[web] is stopping
2015.11.23 08:03:51 INFO  web[o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2015.11.23 08:03:51 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.11.23 08:03:52 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.11.23 08:03:53 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.11.23 08:03:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
```

When I execute the failed ALTER TABLE command in SQL Server Management Studio, it does work. I was able to connect to the sonar database with Visual Studio with the user/password that SonarQube uses. I gave the sonar user schema owner and read and write permissions. I tried changeing from the encrypted password to the clear text password. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you check that the db user has access to only a single SonarQube schema ? It must not have permissions to read multiple schemas.

Comment: I gave it the only the db_owner Role membership. Now it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I added an answer so that you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DB user has permissions to read multiple SonarQube schemas. It must be restricted to a single schema.